# Posso adicionar tabelas de conteúdo na mesma base de dados que dos Utilizadores? ASP.Net identity

Tags: c#, banco-de-dados, asp.net-mvc-5, sql-server, visual-studio-2013

Criei um projeto ASP.Net MVC 5, EF 6 com contas individuais.

A base de dados é gerada automaticamente com 5 tabelas:

- AspNetRoles
- ASpNetUserClaim
- AspNetUserLogins
- AspNetUserRoles
- AspNetUsers

É uma boa prática colocar mais tabelas? Por exemplo:

- Produto
- Categoria
- SubCategorias
- Encomenda ...

Isto ficando tudo na mesma base de dados dos utilizadores, será uma boa prática ou tem de ficar em base de dados separadas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não há qualquer problema em fazer isso.

Os contextos são separados no desenvolvimento apenas pela questão de construir/destruir a base de dados usando a abordagem *Code First*. A ideia é não precisar ficar criando os usuários toda vez que a base é derrubada.

Aproveitando, se você fizer `override` dos métodos de *Identity* padrão para referenciar entidades do seu contexto, a base terá de ser junta de qualquer forma, para aproveitar os dados das demais tabelas do seu sistema.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta!!